# Pull request and push in Azure

Tags: git

In Git, What is the difference between a pull request where I can add a viewer who can approve or reject my code after reviewing  my code before merge into to master repository and a simple push request from a local repository to master repository in GitHub. In practical life, can we use push command and merge code from a local repository to master repository?. Sorry for this very basic question, but I am new in coding and trying to get some knowledge about git and GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

**Pushing** moves code from any branch on your local repository to any branch on a remote repository (in this case GitHub.com). If you push to a branch which is protected, or push to a branch when you don't have all the commits it has, GitHub will automatically reject your push with an explanation.

**Pulling** is the combination of two commands. First it **fetches** all the changes from a remote repository. Then it **merges** those changes into the specified branch. If the remote changes and local changes make different edits to the same file, a merge conflict will occur.

**Pull requests** are requests to **merge** code from one branch in GitHub to another branch in GitHub. This operation strictly takes place on the remote repository. (It GitLab pull requests are called merge requests which I think is a more descriptive name.)